# how to list the selected options and remove the selected options by using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my HTML code and i have to add jquery for this how to do?

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="row one">
    <h4>Staff Re-Admission</h4>
</div><br>
<div class="row">
    <p>Academic Year</p>
    <select>
        <option>2010/2011</option>
        <option>2010/2011</option>
        <option>2010/2011</option>
    </select>
</div><br>
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table" style="width: 100%;">        
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 250px"><p>Staff List</p></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><p>Continue</p></td>
          <td><p>Discontinue</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><select size="14" class="Staff" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="SJB2017NT021">SJB2017NT021--Vishu</option>
            <option value="SJB2017NT022">SJB2017NT022--Naveen</option>
            <option value="SJB2017NT023">SJB2017NT023--Uday</option>
            <option value="SJB2017NT024">SJB2017NT024--Mohan</option>
            <option value="SJB2017TS019">SJB2017TS019--Thejaswini</option>
            <option value="SJB2017TS020">SJB2017TS020--Prasad</option>
          </select></td>
          <td>
            <button type="submit"  value="" id="Continue">Continue >>
            </button><br><br>
            <button type="submit"  value="" id="Discontinue">Discontinue >>
            </button><br><br>
            <button type="submit" value="" id="Back">Back To List 
            <<</button>
          </td>
          <td><select size="14" multiple="multiple" class="Staff" ></select>
          </td>
          <td><select size="14" multiple="multiple" class="Staff" ></select>
          </td>
        <tr>
          <td><button type="submit">submit</button>
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
          </td> 
        </tr>         
        </tr>            
      </tbody>          
    </table>
  </div><!--end of .table-responsive-->
  </div>
  </div>
</div>                       
</div>
</div>
```

when i selcet the option and click on continue it has to be listed in continue box and same if i select discontinue then in discontinue box and if i select back entire thing has to come back how to do this please help me out.

Comment: refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/timotheus/7JHA4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the id of another two select with continue and discontinue

```
<td>
    <select size="14" multiple="multiple" class="continue" ></select>
</td>
<td>
    <select size="14" multiple="multiple" class="discontinue" ></select>
</td>
```

Here is jquery for add to continue and discontinue.

```
<script>
    $("#Continue").on("click", function(){
        var cont = $(".Staff").val();
        $(".continue").append($(".Staff option:selected"));
        $(".Staff option:selected").remove();
        return false;
    });
    $("#Discontinue").on("click", function(){
        var cont = $(".Staff").val();
        $(".discontinue").append($(".Staff option:selected"));
        $(".Staff option:selected").remove();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 methods for each button and on click of each move item to particular box...

on back button click take all items from both the box (Continue and Discontinue) and add them to `<select>` back..
also clear both boxes...